# multiple series of endnotes in eledmac

Tags: endnotes, eledmac

What is the correct way to use multiple series of endnotes with `eledmac`?

Example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{eledmac}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Text}
\beginnumbering
\pstart
\edtext{lemma 1}{\Aendnote{---my endnote to lemma 1}}

text text text

\edtext{lemma 2}{\Bendnote{---my endnote to lemma 2}}\\
\pend
\endnumbering

\section{A series endnotes}
\doendnotes{A}
\section{B series endnotes}
\doendnotes{B}
\end{document}
```

This produces garbage output:

[image: endnote issue output]

If the endnotes are all in the A series, they print normally. The problem also occurs with the `articl`e document class.

Comment: That code does not compile here. It complains about undefined commands e.g. \Bend and \Aend. That's what you are seeing reflected in the output.

Comment: No idea why, though.

Comment: It's a bug in eledmac. I will correct it and say you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said, it was a bug on eledmac.

I have yet corrected and uploaded on CTAN the new version. It will be upgradable in texlive in some days.

If you need it quickly, you can download https://github.com/maieul/ledmac/archive/mac1.8.1-par1.6.0.zip, unzip it, run with pdflatex the .ins files, and put the generated .sty files aside your .tex file.

Comment: This is now uploaded on the CTAN (but there is time for propagation)